# Erro php Pegar Coluna Banco de Dados

Tags: php, laravel

O nome da minha coluna no banco de dados é DATA PASSAGEM (com esse espaço entre as palavras), quando tento acessar pelo html da o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou na duvida, em como posso fazer para o php identificar esse espaço sem modificar o nome na tabela do banco de dados

Comment: Não existe coluna em tabela com espaço, pelo menos até onde eu saiba

Comment: Não é uma boa isso,  mas ->{'nome outronome'} parece que funciona não tenho como testar agora mas mesmo assim altere a base é  melhor

Comment: Virgilio Novic, coloca essa sua sugestão como resposta, pois funcionou o que você passou.

Comment: Em relação eu não poder mudar o nome da coluna no BD, é devido eu não ter permissões para isso, pois é banco de dados da empresa.